# How to call function auto execute after load page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a slider dynamically with jQuery. I'm using an example from http://imageslidermaker.com/v2, and have downloaded the source and copied to my `js` and `css` folders.

My code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/my-slider.css"/>
<script src="../js/ism-2.0.1-min.js"></script>

        <div class="ism-slider" data-transition_type="fade" data-play_type="loop">
              <ul>
                    <li class="ism-slide-Imgs"><img src="../img/PuntaPalma/Suits-1.jpg" class="ism-img-Imgs"></li>
                    <li class="ism-slide-Imgs"><img src="../img/PuntaPalma/Suits-2.jpg" class="ism-img-Imgs"></li>
                    <li class="ism-slide-Imgs"><img src="../img/PuntaPalma/Suits-3.jpg" class="ism-img-Imgs"></li>
                    <li class="ism-slide-Imgs"><img src="../img/PuntaPalma/Suits-2.jpg" class="ism-img-Imgs"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```

with this example the `js` works fine, but when I try to dynamically add the images, the `js` does not work.

```
<div class="ism-slider" data-transition_type="fade" data-play_type="loop">
  <ul>
    <!--li append from jQuery ajax-->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then I open the `js` and I see that it has a function auto execute, so the question is: How to do to execute the function that is inside of `js`  after the page has loaded?

Comment: but the file ism-2.0.1-min.js has the function that auto execute

Comment: Have you tried to insert this line - `<script src="../js/ism-2.0.1-min.js"></script>` just after your `</body>` closing tag?

Comment: yes, but doesn't work..

Comment: How do you add your images dynamically?

Comment: in the method $.ajax success:function ..... i do this 
for(i=0; i< ObjResidence[0].LsImgSuits.length;i++){
$(".ism-slider").append('<li class="ism-slide-Imgs"><img src="'+ObjResidence[0].LsImgSuits[i] +'" class="ism-img-Imgs"></li>');
}

Comment: Ok, do you use any trigger events like `.click()` to start loading your images, or do you load them while loading your page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88609/discussion-between-deathshoo7-and-ramis-wachtler).

Comment: this code load inside of function, that execute in the $(document).ready(function(){myfunction();});

Answer (score 2):

Use onload. Since you are using jq:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

---

I took a look at this slideshow library, and found this which might be of interest to you:

```
<script>
    window.ISMConfig = {no_instantiation:true};
</script>
<script src="/ism/js/ism-2.0.1-min.js?v=150717"></script>
```

Comment: but the file ism-2.0.1-min.js has the function that auto execute

Comment: Are you calling that function?

Comment: this is a part of the code of the file (function(){function q(q){function h(v,b,c){v=v||{};p();!1!==b&&z();I=k=d=null;f=-1;J=C=K=L=null;D=! .... i need call that function after append ajax

Comment: Then you would call that function *after* all your ajax callbacks and the images are loaded. The problem is not the library, no?

Comment: the problem is i can't call that function after append images from ajax, i dont know to do that,

Comment: Supply your ajax code as well as "that function" in the question and I can help you with that.

Comment: Keizom 18, can i talk you with you for chat??

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing your js source, there's a very simple jQuery method for it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

As soon as the document is finished loading, any functions pushed to the `ready` stack via this method will be called.

Comment: but the file ism-2.0.1-min.js has the function that auto execute, i need execute that function after append html with ajax

Comment: The `$.ajax` method's promise has a `done(function(data){...})` that you can call the function from too.